# How can I conditionally swap two lines with sed or other linux tool?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I want to swap two lines, but only if they're in the wrong order. For example, if I have XML lines (anywhere in the file, not necessary in certain locations) like this:

```
<person>
    <given-name>John</given-name> 
    <surname>Smith</surname>
</person>
```

I want to swap lines two and three, so that it produces

```
<person>
    <surname>Smith</surname>
    <given-name>John</given-name> 
</person>
```

But only for files where those lines are out of order. Is there a way to do that with sed, or other linux tool?

Comment: Nope, I want to be able to do this with arbitrary (non-numeric, non-alphabetical-order) lines.

Comment: Is every single line from your file different?

Comment: How do you define `out of order`?

Comment: why not just force a re-write of your file in the order you want (without worrying about logic)? Good luck.

Comment: How do you know which lines are "out of order"?

Comment: I'll edit this question to make a better example to show out of order lines. Basically I want `<surname>` followed by `<given name>` and not the other way around.

Comment: Sounds like you want a proper set of XML parsing/processing tools, not sed/grep/awk/etc...

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed);

```
sed -r '$!N;s/^(\s*<given-name>.*)\n(\s*<surname>.*)/\2\n\1/;P;D' file
```

Read 2 lines at a time and if the combination is wrong swap the lines.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that "line 4" and "line 3" are patterns and not the entire lines:

```
awk -v first="line 4" -v second="line 3" '
    $0 ~ second { seen_second = 1 } 
    $0 ~ first && ! seen_second {
        this_line = $0
        # assume the second line is the *next* line
        getline
        print
        print this_line
        next
    } 
    1
' file
```

This does not modify the file. To do that:

```
awk '...' file > tempfile &&
mv file file.bak &&
mv tempfile file
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like `surname` to come before `given-name` and have this data:

```
cat file
<person>
    <given-name>John</given-name>
    <surname>Smith</surname>
</person>
<person>
    <surname>Hanson</surname>
    <given-name>Thor</given-name>
</person>
```

This `awk` will then change the order of `surname`and `given-name` if its wrong:

```
awk '/<person>/ {f=NR} f && f+1==NR && /<given-name>/ {a=$0;getline;print $0 RS a;next} 1' file
<person>
    <surname>Smith</surname>
    <given-name>John</given-name>
</person>
<person>
    <surname>Hanson</surname>
    <given-name>Thor</given-name>
</person>
```

---

How it works:

```
awk '
/<person>/ {                        # if line include <person> do:
    f=NR}                           # do set flag "f" to line record
f && f+1==NR && /<given-name>/ {    # if flag "f" is true and flag "f+1" equal "NR" and line include <given-name> do:
    a=$0                            # set "a" to current line
    getline                         # get next line
    print $0 RS a                   # print current line and previous line
    next}                           # skip to next record
1                                   # print all other lines
    ' file                          # read the file
```